# Links to change ordering of a posts loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to achieve links in my page that allow me to change the order that my posts display in. Similar to 'Recent', 'Hot' and 'Oldest' on Reddit.

I currently have by default

**PostsController.rb**

```
  def index
      @posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').all.paginate(page: params[:page],      per_page: 20)
  end
```

How would I go about adding links to a method to reverse the flow of posts to ASC or to display posts descending by a specific column on the model like views?

Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create some scopes and a method in the model to handle all the possibilities,

```
# Post.rb
scope :recent, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
scope :hot,    -> { order(something: :desc) }
scope :oldest, -> { order(created_at: :asc) }

def self.sort_by(sort_param)
  case sort_param
  when 'recent'
    recent
  when 'hot'
    hot
  when 'oldest'
    oldest
  else
    all
  end
end

# controller
@posts = Post.sort_by(params[:order]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
```

Since I'm whitelisting, I don't really need to sanitize, any wrong param will return the default order.

If you want you could use `#send` and add method names to the whitelist array, but you need to make sure that the scope exists

```
def self.sort_by(sort_param)
  if %w(recent hot oldest).include? sort_param
    send sort_param
  else
    all
  end
end
```

Comment: How would I link to 'hot' in my rails view with this method?

Comment: `my_posts_path(order: :hot)`, or whatever ordering key you are using

Comment: Do the scopes go in the model or the controller (apols for newbie questions!)

Comment: scopes live in the models, you can read more about them here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: Getting this Exception. **undefined method `sort_by' for #<Class:0x007f8661ea1d40>**

Comment: Doesn't like this line **@posts = Post.sort_by(params[:order]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)**

Comment: ok try `Post.all.sort_by ...` not sure it would make a difference but tell me what it does, the weird thing is that it's saying `#<Class..` and not `#<Post..`

Comment: **wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)** with the 'all' put in. Just to get things straight. I've placed scopes in the model and the method self.sort_by in the controller.

Comment: Apologies, beginner with rails here. Getting this error now **No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :order=>:hot} missing required keys: [:id]**

Comment: you probably used the show path, if you used a path called `post_path` for example, change it to a plural form `posts_path` note the `s`

Comment: How would I default my feed to a specific ordering?

Comment: inside the else, you could replace the `all` with any ordering you want

Answer (score 0):

Use `will_paginate` gem in your app for `Sorting` in both directions and `Paginate`.Visit this link to implement it https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate.

Comment: Can't see anything about the question on that page.

Comment: I think you want to sort your table in ASC and DESC direction?

Comment: I want to order it by anything, ASC and DESC was just an example. I was essentially asking for help to create a method which allows me to sort by a column like Views, ASC, DESC

Answer (score 0):

firstly you want to remove the `all` so that pagination works better.

```
 def index
      @posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
 end
```

then you can use a variable to control the order. The important thing is to sanitise before passing to mysql.

```
 def index
      sort_by = ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize(params.permit(:sort_by))
      @posts = Post.order(sort_by).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
 end
```

Comment: Currently using postgres for my DB, I guess I'll need to change sanitize? Also how would I display a link to that method in my view?

Comment: Active record should recognise the adapter and sanitise the right way. Link path would be: posts_path(sort_by: 'my_attr ASC')

Comment: actually `all` has nothing to do with the pagination doing better or worse, i'd say it's useless but not doing any thing bad, all it does is that it returns the same `ActiveRecord::Relation`