# How do you sort posts in rails and have them reload in AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, sorting

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414349/links-to-change-ordering-of-a-posts-loop) is a good starting point but I'm not sure how to call these methods from the view nor do I know how to update things from the view. The idea is that a nav will sort between Ascending By Date, Descending by date, Upvotes and Down votes. I'm using the act as votable gem
My best guess for my model is

```
#Message.rb
scope :recent, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
scope :upvoted,    -> { order(:cached_votes_up => :desc) }
scope :oldest, -> { order(created_at: :asc) }

def self.sort_by(sort_param)
  case sort_param
  when 'recent'
    recent
  when 'upvoted'
    upvoted
  when 'oldest'
    oldest
  else
    all
  end
end
```

I don't know how to call this method(presumably from the index) and i also don't know how to use AJAX to update the view.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest answer for me was 
Adding the scope's to my model

```
#Message.rb
scope :recent, -> { order("created_at DESC") }
scope :oldest, -> { order(created_at: :asc) }
scope :upvoted, -> { order(:cached_votes_up => :desc) }
scope :downvoted, -> { order(:cached_votes_down => :desc) }
```

Defining the methods in the controller with a render action to the index.

```
#messages_controller.rb
def recent
 @messages = Message.recent
 render action: :index
end

def oldest
 @messages = Message.oldest
 render action: :index
end

def upvoted
 @messages = Message.upvoted
 render action: :index
end

def downvoted
 @messages = Message.downvoted
 render action: :index
end
```

And creating the corresponding routes via a collection.

```
collection do
  get :recent
  get :oldest
  get :upvoted
  get :downvoted
end
```

And my nav on my view.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <%= link_to "Recent", recent_messages_path, class: "nav-link active" %>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <%= link_to "Oldest", oldest_messages_path, class: "nav-link active" %>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <%= link_to "Upvoted", upvoted_messages_path, class: "nav-link active" %>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <%= link_to "Downvoted", downvoted_messages_path, class: "nav-link active" %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My app is here https://boiling-beach-61535.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

you should read the guide

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html and get a better understanding of **AJAX**

How are you going to trigger the method? The user will somehow click a button or a link?

This is an example of how to bind the submit button of a form to an ajax action

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns

Basically the `form button submit` will execute the `users_controller#create` which will execute the following code inside `create.js.erb`

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @user) %>").appendTo("#users");
```

as you see from this example the advantage, is that as this is a `js.erb` file you can use the variable `@user` and just append it to the `#user` div

you can search for **rails ajax** for more informations and you can watch youtube vidoes about **AJAX** to get a better understanding

The idea is that **AJAX** stands for asynchronous javascript and xml request, right now we use json and not xml. The Client side will send a **request** and the server will send a **response**. The information are send through **json** and the **client side** use as scripting language **json**

In your case, I suggest. Identify the `link` or `button` that triggers the `request`, then set up the `rails ajax` by following the guide, configure you `controller#action` to respond with `js` and create the `js.erb` file so that you can reorder the information on the page. You can create an instance of the variable with the list of items reordered in your `controller#action` and then append that `list of items` in your `html` with `javascript`

Comment: The plan is to use a link. I'll try it and report back. Thanks.